# Pycharm path referencing

Tags: python, path

Given the following folder structure:

**Script1.py**

*Relative path*: `project/main/main_gui/script1.py`

*Absolute path*: `C:\Users\timda\PycharmProjects\group-31\project\main\main_gui\script1.py`

**Script2.py**

*Relative path*: `project/Login/Main/script2.py`

*Absolute path*: `C:\Users\timda\PycharmProjects\group-31\project\Login\Main\Main.py`

**Data.csv**

*Relative path*: `data.csv: project/main/data/users.csv`

*Absolute path*: `C:\Users\timda\PycharmProjects\group-31\project\main\data\users.csv`

Where `project` is my root folder (it's deep blue in Pycharm). I've enabled 'Add content roots to PYTHONPATH'.

If `script1.py` imports `script2.py`, and `script2.py` should call `users.csv`, how do I properly specify that csv file's path in `script2.py` in Pycharm? I've tried several paths already, including `r'project/main/data/users.csv'`, `r'main/data/users.csv'`, but they do not seem to work.

Comment: One of these scripts must be the entrypoint to your program, you would have configured this. If you use the relative path from this entrypoint script it should work. If you're not using an absolute path, `r'project/main/data/users.csv` this will be from the `cwd` of your entrypoint python script... which sounds like it wouldn't work

Comment: @JordanSimba Thank you for the reply. The entrypoint would be script1.py. How do I get the relative path?

Comment: Try `../data/users.csv`

Comment: @JordanSimba Unfortunately that doesn't work either

Comment: What are the absolute paths of all the files here? Script1, script2 and the csv? It would be good to get an idea about the file structure on disk

Comment: @JordanSimba I've added the absolute paths to the post.

Comment: Any luck @Tim Rood?

Comment: @JordanSimba yes, it's working now. sorry for the late reply.

Comment: Cool! That's good 

Answer (score 0):

When running programs in Pycharm, you should be aware of how Pycharm might generate the `python` commands that you don't have to write any more!

In general, when a program is ran, the directory from which it's ran from will be the `cwd` and forms a `context`.

A quick way to debug would be to do the following.

- In whichever script is working with the csv file, use the absolute path of the csv file. This should always work *on your system*.
- Add some debugging logs or print statements using the `os` module or `pathlib` whichever you are used to to investigate the true 'context' of your program

```
import os

print(os.getcwd())
print(os.listdir())
my_work()
```

Also please check your Pycharm run configuration for the 'CWD' field. Hopefully this isn't pointing somewhere ridiculous.